Socket force different TCP packages
I'm currently writing a few tests in Python regarding a TCP server of mine. I want to test behaviour when a message is split into multiple different packages. How can I force the OS to actually send the message and not wait for more data to avoid sending small packages? Just waiting time.sleep is not an option.
    def send(self, msg: Union[str,List[str]]):
        if isinstance(msg, list):
            for m in msg:
                self.s.sendall(m.encode())
        else:                
            self.s.sendall(msg.encode())


When your function is passed a list of strings just join them and send the result of the join (encoded obviously)

@SIGHUP how does this make sure it splits the message exaclty like i wanted? It may split it if it's large enough acording to the current tcp window, but it may not split at all.

I obviously misunderstood your question so let me ask you... In what way does your code not achieve your objective?

Say i want to send(["a", "b"]), i need it to send 2 tcp messages, one containing a and one containing b. But it packs both together to "ab"

You need to devise a protocol such that the server can know what constitutes the start and end of a message. There are various ways to do that. A common technique is to send a network-independent value that is of a fixed length that contains the size of the following message

@SIGHUP I just want to send 2 tcp messages . Nothing more. But i want it to be two  messages. And not the contents of 2 being combined into one.

Packages? Do you mean packets? or segments? What exactly are you talking about?

Sorry, i mean 2 seperate tcp packets. meaning i want to send one message in 2 tcp packets. maybe to clarify even further: tcp's default minimum packet size is someting like 500 bits (or something like that). but i want to send packets smaller than that without delay

@FrontendC I think you're going to have to explain what you mean by "tcp packets" and also why none of the answers given so far don't (apparently) solve your problem

“ i want to send packets smaller than that without delay”. That sounds like you want to disable the Nagle algorithm with the TCP_NODELAY option.

TCP doesn't work that way.  It is a byte-streaming protocol and the only guarantee is you will get the bytes in the same order received.  You are responsible for sending those bytes in a way that you can determine what is a complete message.
Consider how a text file on disk works.  A file is just a stream of bytes.  How would you read a line if there were no newline characters in the file?  Or a binary file of records...The records would need to be fixed size or contain information about the length of each record.  This all applies to sockets as well.
There is a method called socket.makefile that wraps a socket in a file-like object.  This object buffers the reads and writes of a socket and allows methods like .readline() and .read(n) to read a newline-terminated line of data or exactly n bytes from a socket (less if the socket is closed, just like a disk-based file).
Here is an example of a simple protocol that sends a 4-byte big-endian integer as the length of a message followed by the message itself:
server.py
import socket

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.bind(('', 5000))
    s.listen()
    while True:
        client, addr = s.accept()
        with client, client.makefile('rb') as rfile:
            while True:
                data = rfile.read(4)
                if not data: break  # socket closed
                length = int.from_bytes(data)
                message = rfile.read(length)
                print(f'{addr}: {message}')

client.py
import socket

def send_message(sock, msg):
    sock.sendall(len(msg).to_bytes(4) + msg)

with socket.socket() as s:
    s.connect(('localhost', 5000))
    send_message(s, b'abc')
    send_message(s, b'defghijk')
    send_message(s, b'lmnop')

Output of server after one run of client:
('127.0.0.1', 2480): b'abc'
('127.0.0.1', 2480): b'defghijk'
('127.0.0.1', 2480): b'lmnop'


Does len(msg).to_bytes(4) create the byte sequence in a network neutral manner - e.g., as the "!L" format for struct.pack would do?

@SIGHUP Yes int.to_bytes defaults to byteorder='big'.

"You are responsible for sending those bytes in a way that you can determine what is a complete message." - and thats exactly what i am trying to test on my server. i want to send ONE message, split up into mulitple TCP packets.

@FrontendC that’s not what you said. You said two messages that each is in its own TCP packet instead of joined. What you may want is the TCP_NODELAY option, but it still won’t guarantee coalescing of packets.

Your server needs to know what constitutes a "message". A common strategy is to send the length of the significant message in a format that is understood by both the client and the server.
Here's a complete working example which you may be able to adapt:
from socket import socket
from threading import Thread

ADDRESS = ("localhost", 1234)

def read(conn, nbytes):
    buffer = b""
    while len(buffer) < nbytes:
        if rb := conn.recv(nbytes - len(buffer)):
            buffer += rb
        else:
            return None
    return buffer

def getmessage(conn):
    if (b := read(conn, 4)) is not None:
        mlen = int.from_bytes(b)
        return read(conn, mlen)

def server():
    with socket() as s:
        s.bind(ADDRESS)
        s.listen()
        conn, _ = s.accept()
        while (msg := getmessage(conn)) is not None:
            print(msg.decode())
        conn.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    (thread := Thread(target=server)).start()
    with socket() as s:
        s.connect(ADDRESS)
        messages = ["a", "b", "Hello world!"]
        for message in messages:
            emsg = message.encode()
            mlen = len(emsg).to_bytes(4)
            s.sendall(mlen + emsg)
    thread.join()

Output:
a
b
Hello world!

